# jQuery data-attribute to object with stringify reversing on newer versions

Tags: html, jquery, custom-data-attribute

When retrieving the data-attribute on a HTML element I have run into a problem using jQuery.

I wish to manipulate the attributes and some elements have more data-attributes than others.

Using *jquery-1.10.1.js* when converting to JSON it works fine, i.e. the order as they appear on the HTML element.

(data-id, data-col, data-sport + any additional data)

If I replace jQuery version *jquery-1.10.2* to a later version starting with, *jquery-1.11.0* it does the opposite and has the last data-attribute first.
(in the code snippet is the older version of jQuery showing how it should look).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btnOne").on('click', function(){
        
        a = $(this).data();
        b = JSON.stringify(a)
    
    var count=Object.keys(a).length;

        console.log("a: "+b+" -- "+Object.keys(a));
        console.log("KEY: --- "+Object.keys(a)[2]);
    
        if(a[Object.keys(a)[2]]=="Golf"){
            console.log("CHANGE"); 
            a[Object.keys(a)[2]] = "Snooker";
            $(this).html(a[Object.keys(a)[2]]);
        };
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="btnOne" data-id="14" data-col="R" data-sport="Rugby">Rugby</p>
<p class="btnOne" data-id="12" data-col="B" data-sport="Cricket" data-team="Somerset" >Cricket</p>
<p class="btnOne" data-id="23" data-col="Y" data-sport="Golf">Golf</p>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd update a dusty ancient version of jQuery with a very slightly less dusty ancient version. Load v3.x and then make your fixes.

Comment: Why does the order of the data- attributes matter? Write your code so that it doesn't matter. I.e., if you expect `Object.keys(a)[2]` to be "sport", just use `a.sport`.

Comment: Also, alerts are a nightmare. Use console logs.

Comment: If order is important, use arrays, not objects. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Comment: HTML element attribute ordinality can't be guaranteed